# Cannot find module 'mini-css-extract-plugin' in vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

I'm having problems with `npm run dev`. It keeps on telling me that module `webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs` cannot be found. Modules added like `webpack`, `webpack-cli`, and `webpack-dev-server` are on their latest versions. Anyone who also experienced same issue?

I already tried reinstalling the modules stated above and looked around github and stack forums for solution and none of them worked for me

**`package.json`:**

```
scripts: {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config 
            build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit test/e2e/specs",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
},
devDependencies: {
    "webpack": "^4.28.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.13",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0"
}
```

Modules are already installed and it should start running instead of throwing

> Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'

---

**UPDATE 12/26/2018**

`webpack v4` doesn't support `extract-text-webpack-plugin` so I replaced it with `mini-css-extract-plugin` and now it shows this result

> Cannot find module 'mini-css-extract-plugin'

Comment: Maybe something was wrong in your `webpack.dev.conf.js`? You could provide that code.

Comment: It's working now. I made another project and added `mini-css-extract-plugin` at devDependencies, and updated webpack.dev.cong.js :)

Answer (score 1):

**FINALLY**

So I created a new project and added `mini-css-extract-plugin` in devDependencies and updated `webpack.dev.conf.js` with

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
```

since `extract-text-webpack-plugin` is deprecated when using webpack v4 and now it works!